# cards responsive for smallaer screens img being cut

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

i have a card that no matter what i did to it i could not make it a perfect responsive for smaller screens some of the images will cut off i need to make it very small for that then the medum screen will be ruined i dont know what to do here is my codes 
and here is some images of how it looks like and what will happen when it is on small screen
[big screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsBw4.jpg)   [small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9G9Z.jpg) like you see in both sides the it cuts the image can anyone help me with this ?

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1{
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

.wrapper{
  width: 100%;

  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: max-width: 80rem;;

}

.cols{

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.col{

  width: calc(25% - 2rem);
  margin: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container{
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
         perspective: 1000px;
}

.front,
.back{
  word-wrap: break-word;
 
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    

  background-size: 400px 400px;
 background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
 transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
 -o-transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
 transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
 transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1), -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
         backface-visibility: hidden;
 text-align: center;
 min-height: 400px;
  min-width: 200px;
 height: auto;
 border-radius: 10px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 0.8rem;
text-overflow: ellipsis;


  
}

.back{
    background-color: #000;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  #cedce7 0%,#596a72 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  #cedce7 0%,#596a72 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,  #cedce7 0%,#596a72 100%);

  

}

.front:after{
 position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    opacity: .3;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.container:hover .front,
.container:hover .back{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    -o-transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1), -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
}

.back{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;


}

.inner{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
            transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2rem;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-perspective: inherit;
            perspective: inherit;
    z-index: 2;

}

.container .back{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;

}

.container .front{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.container:hover .back{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
          transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.container:hover .front{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front .inner p{
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative;

}

.front .inner p:after{
  content: '';
  width: 4rem;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #C6D4DF;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: -.75rem;

}

.front .inner span{
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 300;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 64rem){
  .col{
    width: calc(33.333333% - 2rem);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 48rem){
  .col{
    width: calc(50% - 2rem);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 32rem){
  .col{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 p-2 col-6" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
        <div class="container">
          <a href="viewmovie.php?series=<?php echo $id; ?>&episode=<?php echo $id_ep ?>">
         <div class="front" style="background-image: url(../../src/upload/posts/<?php echo $img; ?>)" >
            
            <div class="inner">
              <h5><?php echo "$name"; ?></h5>
              <h6>خوله‌ک  <?php echo "$time";  ?> </h6>
              <p></p>
              <h6>IMDb: <?php echo $rate ?></h6>
               <h6 class="fa fa-eye"> <?php echo "$views"; ?> </h6>
              <span> </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <div class="inner">
              <p><?php echo "$description"; ?></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <center><a target="_blank" href= "<?php echo $trailer2 ?>"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2"><span class="fa fa-play">ترایله‌ر</button></span></a></center>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
/* import font */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
header{
    margin: 0;
}
a, li{
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav{
   text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav-link + .nav-link{
    margin-left: 30px;
}
nav ul li + nav ul li{
    margin-right: 30px;
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}
.products{
     padding: 30px 50px 100px 50px ;
 }
.card{
    max-width: 20%;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: right; display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    animation: rotation 1s ease-in-out ;
}
@keyframes rotation {
    from {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotateY(359deg);
    }
}
.card-body div{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.card-footer button{
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: #fb727c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.product-name{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "Raleway Medium", sans-serif;
}
.product-price{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: "Raleway Medium", sans-serif;
}
button{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Raleway SemiBold", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 8px 25px 8px 25px;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
button:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(239, 60, 73, 0.5);
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background: rgb(239, 60, 73);
}
img{
    max-width: 100%;
}
/* media queries */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .products{
        padding: 30px 20px 30px 20px;
    }
    .card{
        max-width: 40%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .card {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="nav-link"><a class="nav-item" href="">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-link"><a class="nav-item" href="">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-link"><a class="nav-item" href="">Service</a></li>
            <li class="nav-link"><a class="nav-item" href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<main>
    <div class="products">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="product-img">
                    <img src="https://www.nowfoods.com/sites/default/files/styles/home_site_sections/public/beauty-health-catagory-homepage_0.png?itok=wSmkgxgp" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="product-details">
                    <div class="product-name">Short denim dungarees</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-price">
                    ₹1,900
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <a href=""><button>Add to Cart</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="product-img">
                    <img src="https://www.nowfoods.com/sites/default/files/styles/home_site_sections/public/beauty-health-catagory-homepage_0.png?itok=wSmkgxgp" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="product-details">
                    <div class="product-name">Short denim dungarees</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-price">
                    ₹1,900
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <a href=""><button>Add to Cart</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="product-img">
                    <img src="https://www.nowfoods.com/sites/default/files/styles/home_site_sections/public/beauty-health-catagory-homepage_0.png?itok=wSmkgxgp" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="product-details">
                    <div class="product-name">Short denim dungarees</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-price">
                    ₹1,900
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <a href=""><button>Add to Cart</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="product-img">
                    <img src="https://www.nowfoods.com/sites/default/files/styles/home_site_sections/public/beauty-health-catagory-homepage_0.png?itok=wSmkgxgp" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="product-details">
                    <div class="product-name">Short denim dungarees</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-price">
                    ₹1,900
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <a href=""><button>Add to Cart</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="product-img">
                    <img src="https://www.nowfoods.com/sites/default/files/styles/home_site_sections/public/beauty-health-catagory-homepage_0.png?itok=wSmkgxgp" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="product-details">
                    <div class="product-name">Short denim dungarees</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-price">
                    ₹1,900
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <a href=""><button>Add to Cart</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="product-img">
                    <img src="https://www.nowfoods.com/sites/default/files/styles/home_site_sections/public/beauty-health-catagory-homepage_0.png?itok=wSmkgxgp" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="product-details">
                    <div class="product-name">Short denim dungarees</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-price">
                    ₹1,900
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <a href=""><button>Add to Cart</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="product-img">
                    <img src="https://www.nowfoods.com/sites/default/files/styles/home_site_sections/public/beauty-health-catagory-homepage_0.png?itok=wSmkgxgp" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="product-details">
                    <div class="product-name">Short denim dungarees</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-price">
                    ₹1,900
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <a href=""><button>Add to Cart</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="product-img">
                    <img src="https://www.nowfoods.com/sites/default/files/styles/home_site_sections/public/beauty-health-catagory-homepage_0.png?itok=wSmkgxgp" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="product-details">
                    <div class="product-name">Short denim dungarees</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-price">
                    ₹1,900
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <a href=""><button>Add to Cart</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</main>
</body>
```